# Request without output Swift 3

Tags: http, asynchronous, request, swift3

I have that code

```
typealias escHandler = ( URLResponse?, Data? ) -> Void

func getRequest(url : URL, _ handler : @escaping escHandler){
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: url){ (data,response,error) in
    print("--")
        handler(response,data)
}
task.resume()  
}
```

I wanna get output from this call, but, for some reason the program just finish without output.

```
  let x = "someURL"
  let url  = URL(string: x)!
  getRequest(url: url){ response,data in
            print("Handling")
        }
```

That's my problem, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but if by any chance you are using a "http" URL and not a "https" url then you have to make the following change to the info.plist file

Add "App Transport Security Settings" -> Add "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set it to "YES". 
Refer the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Abhra, but i using swift as script, i don't have any plist.